# Ionic project - platform add android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, card.io

Hi I am tryng to develop ionic app.

I am able to runn the app in google chrome with

```
ionic serve
```

But when ı try to add platfrom android,

I am getting this error.

```
D:\aaa>ionic platform add android Adding android project...


Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

        Path: platforms\android
        Package: ionstore.ionicpremium.app
        Name: Ionstore
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-25

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Android project created with cordova-android@6.1.2


Installing "card.io.cordova.mobilesdk" for android


Failed to install 'card.io.cordova.mobilesdk':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:213:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

I am looking for google with

> Failed to install 'card.io.cordova.mobilesdk':Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code ENOENT

But no solution.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Do you have the Android Build Tools installed on your system (usually installed with Android Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
download and install java and android-sdk

add environment variables for

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

ANDROID_HOME = Path_to_android_sdk

Into your android sdk find SDK Manager.exe.
open SDK Manager.exe with Run as administrator.

now download android sdk build tools version 24/25 and
download android api->sdk platform version 25

[image]